# An exercise of complex series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \cfrac{nz^n}{1-z^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cfrac{z^n}{(1-z^n)^2}$ for $|z|<1$.

The hint is to develop in a double series and reverse the order of summation. But I tried a lot and don't know which part to expand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We shall use the identity
\begin{align}
\frac{z}{(1-z)^2} = \sum^\infty_{n=1} nz^{n}.
\end{align}
Observe we have
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{z^n}{(1-z^n)^2} = \sum^\infty_{n=1}\sum^\infty_{k=1}kz^{nk} = \sum^\infty_{k=1}k\sum^\infty_{n=1}z^{nk} = \sum^\infty_{k=1}k\frac{z^{k}}{1-z^k}.
\end{align}